# How to map using i18next json in react

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, i18next

First of all, ㅔlease understand that you use a translator because you are not proficient in English.

How to render static i18next json file for multilingual support in react?

using: *react, Typescript, Styled-components, i18next*

---

### Translation json file used in i18next

```
{
    "miniTitle":"MiniTitle",
    "title":"Title",
    "text": "Text",
    "version":[
        {
            "name": "v1",
            "sensor": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
            "src":"../dist/img/product.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "v2",
            "sensor": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H"],
            "src":"../dist/img/product2.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { MwsCard } from '@Components/index';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { Wrap, Container, TitleH5, TitleH2, TextP1, CardContainer } from './ProductWsStyle';

function ProductWs() {
  const [t] = useTranslation('productWsDB');
  const TransDB = [
    {
      name: t('version.0.name'),
      sensor: [t('version.0.sensor')],
      src: t('version.0.src'),
    },
    {
      name: t('version.1.name'),
      sensor: [t('version.1.sensor')],
      src: t('version.1.src'),
    },
  ];
  return (
    <Wrap>
      <Container>
        <TitleH5>{t('miniTitle')}</TitleH5>
        <TitleH2>{t('title')}</TitleH2>
        <TextP1>{t('text')}</TextP1>
        <CardContainer>
          {TransDB.map(item => (
            <MwsCard key={item.name} name={item.name} sensor={item.sensor} src={item.src} />
          ))}
        </CardContainer>
      </Container>
    </Wrap>
  );
}

export default ProductWs;
```

I think declaring TransDB and writing t() in it is very inefficient. Also, static keystrokes like version.1.name are not cool.

---

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Container, Img, Info, Spec, Title } from './MwsCardStyle';
import { Version } from './MwsProdDBType';

function MwsCard({ name, sensor, src }: Version) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Img src={src} alt={name} />
      <Info>
        <Title>{name}</Title>
        {sensor.map(item => (
          <Spec key={item}>{item}</Spec>
        ))}
      </Info>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default MwsCard;
```

The following error occurs in the sensor.map() section:
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, sensor, src}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Except for the above errors, other parts are rendered and translated normally.

### I want to know how to solve the error and write a more efficient code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DBJson` version is an array, calling `Object.keys` on an array provides an array of indexes.

`Object.keys(DBJson.version)` will output `["0", "1"]` because arrays in javascript are special kind of object which keys are numbers, so `Object.keys` will produce the array of keys which are array of numbers.

If you want to render your array properly you will need to use the version array as is:

```
        <CardContainer>
          {DBJson.version.map((version, i) => (
            <MwsCard key={i} name={version.name} sensor={version.sensor} src={version.src} />
          ))}
        </CardContainer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
But what I want is to receive, forward, translate and render data name of json file used by i18n.

I took a hint from your answer and corrected it, but some errors occurred.

I edited the question with the newly revised content.

I'd be very grateful if you could give me another hint.

Comment: What are your errors? One problem I could catch in your code that `const [t] = useTranslation();` should be `const {t} = useTranslation();` (notice the curly brackets ({}) instead of square brackets ([])), useTranslations returns an object, not an array.

Comment: Thank you for your quick attention.

You just edited a new question. Please review it.

Comment: In your code the useTranslation hook still wrong, change `const [t] = useTranslation();` to `const {t} = useTranslation();`